# Getting Cycles\EEVEE render pipeline events using Python

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

How to to get info about the different render pipeline stages while image is being rendered, such as time?

For example we are using [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io/) and we want to collect render
stages info\status using Python.

1. loading scene graph
2. loading textures
3. render
4. saving file

Etc.

Comment: the console output? are you running on windows or unix or linux?

Comment: The Tasks runs on linux,
we wonder if there is some call back or events we can pull info from, using python.

Comment: were u able to find a solution?

Comment: Nope,one of blender developers offered us to develop this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly render your animation (example *myblend.blend*) from the terminal using the following command:

```
blender --background myblend.blend --render-anim
```

which will give you output progress in real time as it renders as shown in this example:

[image]

You can also store the output directly into a text file by appending the syntax `> output.txt` (overwrite file) or `>> output.txt` (append to file) to the command:

```
blender --background myblend.blend --render-anim >> myoutput.txt
```

You can also start an interactive Blender session in the terminal with a python console (do `import bpy` after starting) to do the other functions via python like (1) loading scene graph, (2) loading textures, (3) other types of rendering, and (4) saving a file.

```
$ blender --background myblend.blend --python-console
```

Here you can run any python command like `import bpy` and `bpy.ops.render.render()` and see the output progress in real time:

```
[akiko@akiko-system]:~/Desktop $ blender --background temp.blend --python-console
Blender 3.2.1 (hash a2d59b2dac9e built 2022-07-05 23:53:28)
Read prefs: /home/akiko/.config/blender/3.2/config/userpref.blend
Read blend: /home/akiko/Desktop/temp.blend
Python 3.10.2 (main, Apr 26 2022, 10:33:12) [GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import bpy
>>> bpy.ops.render.render()
Fra:1 Mem:13.17M (Peak 13.19M) | Time:00:00.13 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Cube
Fra:1 Mem:13.17M (Peak 13.19M) | Time:00:00.13 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Cube.001
Fra:1 Mem:13.17M (Peak 13.19M) | Time:00:00.13 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Cube.003
Fra:1 Mem:13.17M (Peak 13.19M) | Time:00:00.13 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Cube.005
```

Here is a list of more commands: https://linuxcommandlibrary.com/man/blender